# Restrict access to vhost on apache to certificates of one domain only

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I need an Apache server to offer multiple vhosts. Every vhost should only be accessible by one customer. To clear it up, I'll make a small example:

- vhost1: Servername: cust1.example.com
- vhost2: Servername: cust2.example.com

Now, only hosts from customer1 shoud be able to access vhost1 and only hosts from customer2 should be able to access vhost2. Here is what I did so far:

- Set up a CA using openxpki (works)
- Created a certificate for every vhost and configured the vhosts appropriately (works)
- Imported the root certificate of the CA into server and clients (works)
- Tested if Client-SSL-Auth works without filtering. (Works)

But now I can't get the filtering to work. I would like to filter for the CN in the certificates. For vhost1 this would be that all certificates with a CN of "*.cust1.example.com" would be allowed to access the ressource. How can I achieve this?

**Bonus: Would be great to be abble to manage the change with puppet**

Regards, Christian

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to create one (intermediate or root) CA per customer, and use that to issue certificates for each customer

You would then configure each vhost to *require* the clients provide a certificate, and ensure the appropriate CA was used to validate their certificates (e.g. SSLCACertificateFile would be unique per customer/vhost/domain).

A less file/CA-heavy approach (but one possibly more prone to errors) might involve a single client CA, and using SSLRequire to match the O(rganisation) or OU fields set in client certs (it avoids needing to have a CN for a person that looks like 'Bob Smith.the.customer.domain.tld').

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire for details.

Comment: I can confirm this one. As far as I read this might be a good solution in OPs case. Good job.